# Chrome extension inject js

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I want to create a new chrome extension but it don't work.
I want to inject a js file into web page (all web page,not only one.If i push the chrome icon on google the script must execute,if i push the icon on facebook it must execute ect.)

this is background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

chrome.tabs.executeScript({

    null,{file: "backgrounds.js"} });
});
```

this is backgrounds.js

```
document.body.innerHTML="display div elem with style and id";
```

this is manifest.json

```
{
"name": "MyExt",
"description": "an extension,what else?",
"version": "1.0",
"permissions": [
    "activeTab"


],
"content_scripts": [
  {
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "js": ["background.js"]
  }
],
"browser_action": {
    "default_title": "myExt"
},
"manifest_version": 2
}
```

what i wrong?
I'm on windows 8.1 Update 1 with chrome last version

Comment: Pro tip: don't name your different files `background.js` and `backgrounds.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your manifest is wrong: you should set `background.js` as your background script:

```
"background" : { "scripts" : [ "background.js" ] },
```

and remove the `"content_scripts"` section.

---

The `"activeTab"` permission means that you don't need to specify host permissions to inject in the current tab upon browser action click, so no other permissions are needed.

---

The `tabId` argument is optional, you can just drop it instead of passing `null`. And your invocation is wrong (you're wrapping two arguments in a single object). Here's the correct way:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: "backgrounds.js"});
});
```

Comment: Thanks of all have you yet a statue? :D